# Different table name and entity name in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I have an existing database. Lets say that I have a table named `"transactions"` and I want to create the corresponding Entity named `"Transaction"`. How can I do that?

Answer (score 40):

you can set the name of the table using the @ORM\Table annotation

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @ORM\Table(name="transactions")
 */
class Transaction
{
```

If you don't use Annotations, you can find details about other mappings [from this link.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information)

BTW, You can also [generate Entities from an Existing Database.](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/doctrine/reverse_engineering.html)

Answer (score -1):

You could set name param for mapping
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information

Comment: This link just goes to a large documentation page. Was there something specific you were trying to answer with?